# How the Lagrangian is affected by a particular constraint?

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative

I want to find optimal demands for a utility function in the form:
$$U_{1}(c_{1},c_{2})=c_{1}^{1-a}\cdot c_{2}^{a}$$

It is related to an altruistic behaviour, where $c_1$ is the consumption of the consumer and $c_2$ is the consumption of the other one. The exercise has several points, where the last two suppose an income tax and then a "charitable deduction" from that tax when the consumer behaves in an altruistic way (a deduction equal to the amount spent in $c_2$). Finally, the price of the goods is supposed to be =1$.

I can clearly notice that his/her "goodness" depends on $a$, and that a tax means that income=$(1-t)I$ while the effect of the deduction means:
$$income=c_1 + (1-t)c_2=I(1-t)$$

The problem is that I cannot see how to plug this new constraint into the Lagrangian function.

For the fact that for optimizing the "standard" condition, I would have $g(x)=(I-c_1-c_2)$, then in this case I did:
$$L=c_{1}^{1-a}\cdot c_{2}^{a}+\lambda [I-tI-c_{1}-c_{2}+tc_{2}]$$
But the results are wrong, and I think that the problem is here and not in the partial derivatives calculation.

Edit: Maybe the new definition of income should be:
$$income=c_1 + (1-t)c_2=I(1-tc_2)$$

But then, how $g(x)$ in the Lagrangian is modified?

Thank you all